# Fixing GLSL shaders for Nvidia and AMD

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, nvidia

I am having problems getting my GLSL shaders to work on both AMD and Nvidia hardware.

I am not looking for help fixing a particular shader, but how to generally avoid getting these problems. Is it possible to check if a shader will compile on AMD/Nvidia drivers without running the application on a machine with the respective hardware and actually trying it?

I know, in the end, testing is the only way to be sure, but during development I would like to at least avoid the obvious problems.

Everyone using GLSL must have these problems, so why can't I find a good way to fix them?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Using opengl4.x/glfw/glew mostly I had to fix function pointers. Assume glGenVertexArrays is working for AMD but not for Nvidia. So you'll need to retreive the address of the function: glGenVertexArrays = (PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSPROC) glfwGetProcAddress("glGenVertexArrays");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to check if a shader will compile on AMD/Nvidia drivers without running the application on a machine with the respective hardware and actually trying it?

No. If you are going to be serious about developing applications, testing on a variety of hardware is the *only* reliable way to go about it. And if you're not going to be serious, then who cares.

Generally speaking, the easiest way to handle this for a small team is to avoid the problem altogether. Most driver incompatibilities come from attempting to do something unorthodox: passing arrays as output/input varying variables, passing matrices as attributes, using more recent driver features, etc. So... don't do that. Use only solid, safe stuff that's been around in GLSL and has been almost certainly used in real-world OpenGL applications.

Comment: Also, if you can identify something as a bug or violation of the OpenGL spec and can provide a solid test case, file bug reports. Getting feedback from end application developers is the only way for GPU vendors to efficiently fix problems in drivers, firmware or even hardware.

Comment: Another thing you can do practically is check for warnings using `glGetShaderInfoLog`. I have found the NVidia driver in particular to be quite permissive about what it accepts, but it does issue warnings for (at least some of) the dodgy GLSL it compiles.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clear answer that there is no easy tool which can check if a shader is valid for the two vendors.
@GuyRT I am already checking the ShaderInfoLog and it contains nothing on my machine (AMD), but on my friends computer (Nvidia) the application crashes with shader compile errors. I just wanted to know if there is a better method than asking him to send me the exception details.

Comment: Ok, I made a little mistake while reading out the `glShaderInfoLog`. Now I get a few warnings at least.

Answer (score 3):

using NVidias's NVEmulate and AMD's GPU ShaderAnalyzer could be an option.

AMD's GPU ShaderAnalyzer is a stand-alone GLSL/HLSL compiler. NVidias's NVEmulate is a tool to emulate the features of different (better) NVidia graphic cards in software. So if you have an NVidia card, you can simply run your program to test it (possibly emulating another NVidia card with the NVEmulate) and use the ShaderAnalyser to see if your shader compile on AMD cards.

If your shader runs on AMD, it will most probably run on NVidia. You can still test this with cgc (NVidias stand-alone Cg compiller, part of the Cg Toolkit) it compiles GLSL and Cg code to binary or cross-compile it to HLSL. This is the compiler which NVidia drivers use for GLSL anyway. 
The bonus is that you can also see the binary/assembly code of your shader, which is very helpful for low-level optimizations.

What no tool can tell you is, if the shader works (as expected) on different hardware.. I recently found out that some new AMD driver don't handle default uniform values properly... without a warning or error message... but this is a different story. 
So at some point you have to test your code on the target hardware.

Comment: Please include more detail; as it stands this is insufficient for an answer.

Comment: Does ShaderAnalyzer actually bundle a GLSL compiler with it? I thought it interfaced with the driver's compiler and this is why it required a Catalyst driver >= 12.x. They never bothered updating it though, so it does not generate assembly for GLSL for Radeon HD 7xxx or newer GPUs :-\ As far as an HLSL compiler, it certainly does not include this - Microsoft is the only party that writes an HLSL compiler, D3D drivers actually work with compiled byte code and translate it into native instructions for the target GPU.

Comment: yes, ShaderAnalyzer bundle GLSL compiler, it works perfectly on my Nvidia card(s).. and the question was about GLSL. Since HLSL compiller are only provided by Microsoft one usually dont't have problems like this there... provided one really wants (for some reason) to develop with d3d